# python yt api "The request is missing a valid API key."

Tags: python, api, youtube

im using the youtube api in python, i using this code :

```
   r = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos')
   print(r.text)
```

and i get this output :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}


Process finished with exit code 0
```

i already have my api key so my question is how do i add this api key to the GET request and make this work

Answer (score 1):

The API key should be added as a GET parameter called `key`, like so:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=YOUR_API_KEY&id=7lCDEYXw3mM&...')
print(r.text)
```

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) has a few more examples.

Comment: what is the id?

Comment: That's just an example. There are a few more required fields on this request, which are all listed in the [reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list), but the `key` is the one you asked about.